# boto3 list_objects_v2 returns all recursive folders and throws no error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am new to aws and currently reading objects from S3 bucket.

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

bucket = 'my_bucket'
key = 'folder/10'
contents = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=f"{bucket}", Prefix=key)
contents.get('Contents')
```

The bucket does not contain any folder as `folder/10` instead it contains `folder/100`. `list_objects_v2` and `list_objects` recursively patches the path and returns `Key` as `folder/100` in the `Contents` dict.

How do I make sure it gives me an exception error if the path `my_bucket/folder/10` does not exist in S3. ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It does not patch anything.  It returns all objects that start with `folder/10`, which `folder/100` is one.  If you want to list all objects that start with `folder/10/`, then ask for that.  As for returning an error on zero objects, that is not the behavior of the API, you'd have to throw an error if it returns zero entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying that `10` is the name of a 'folder', and you only wish to list the *contents* of that folder, then use: `Prefix='folder/10/`

Please note that folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3. For example, you could upload a file to `invoices/january.txt` even if the `invoices` folder does not exist. That folder will then 'magically' appear! Then, if the object is deleted, the folder will magically 'disappear' because it never actually existed.

The **Key** (filename) of an Amazon S3 object includes the full path to the object, so that object is called `invoices/january.txt`, not just `january.txt` inside a folder.

If no objects are found in a given prefix, then an empty result set will be returned. It will *not* trigger an exception, although you could use the `raise` command in your code to generate an exception in such a situation.